# Antlr4 Can I listen to my own visitor?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

- I understand that Antlr generates a tree walker and I can sub-class the `BaseListener` to act when the tree walker traverses over key items in the parse tree.
- I understand that I can also create my own visitor, by sub-class `BaseVisitor` to navigate the parse tree in my own way.

Can I have my listener that responds to my own visitor?
 I think I made a boo-boo and placed my application code unnecessarily in my sub-classed visitor.

I now believe the visitor should only visit and my listener should trigger events in my application code.

I think I got a little bit muddled in my implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  you can create whatever listener interface you want and then create a visitor that fires events to your listener. It's pretty inefficient however. Just dump your visitor and have the standard tree walker fire events at your listener :)

Comment: Thanks Terence, I've come to realise that the use of my visitor is completely redundant, as with a listener I can still navigate upwards downwards in the parse tree to gather "stuff", can't I?

Comment: Yup. You can navigate all you want, just don't alter the tree ;)